# pygame does not close files after play

Tags: python, windows, urllib, python-3.6

```
from urllib.request import URLopener
from urllib.parse   import quote
from pygame import mixer

def speak(text):
    downloader = URLopener()
    downloader.addheader('Referer', 'https://translate.google.com/')
    downloader.addheader('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36')
    downloader.retrieve('https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q={0}&tl=en&client=tw-ob'.format(quote(text)), 'storage/tts.mp3')
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('storage/tts.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
```

Here is the mine code when I try to use funtion in second time it gives me error(sorry for bad english)

```
downloader.retrieve('https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q={
    0}&tl=en&client=tw-ob'.format(quote(text)), 'storage/tts.mp3')
      File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request
    .py", line 1800, in retrieve
        tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'storage/tts.mp3'
```

Comment: Not a urllib issue (btw, you may want to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) instead), unless urllib didn't close() it. Your program couldn't open the file for writing. Do you have it open somewhere else?

Comment: Seems to be a permission denied on the file caused by the retrieve call, possibly cased by the fact that your mixer is still holding handles on that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a permission denied on the file caused by the retrieve call, possibly cased by the fact that your mixer is still holding handles on that file. Suggest stopping the play with

```
mixer.music.stop()
```

If that doesnt work, try opening the file before you retrieve it

```
from urllib.request import URLopener
from urllib.parse   import quote
from pygame import mixer

def speak(text):
    downloader = URLopener()
    downloader.addheader('Referer', 'https://translate.google.com/')
    downloader.addheader('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36')
    mp3_file = open('storage/tts.mp3')
    downloader.retrieve('https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q={0}&tl=en&client=tw-ob'.format(quote(text)), mp3_file)
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('storage/tts.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
    mixer.music.stop()
    mp3_file.close()
```

More details here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pygame-mirror-on-google-groups/XjSh9zs8j0U

Also consider removing the file when you're done with it.

Comment: as you said pygame still holding the mp3 `mixer.music.stop()` worked!